# Windows client for MySQL 4.1

Tags: mysql, mysql4

Today i find myself administrating a 2003 MySQL database, does anyone know a Windows Client for MySQL 4.1?

I tried Workbench, DbVisualizer and DBeaver.

The problem mainly is from the auth, somewhere around version 4, MySQL changed the auth method, and the new clients no longer support that kind of connection.

Workbench in particular has an "use old authentication method" as a advanced option, but it seems that it's not enough.

I tried console connection and works just fine, but they are simply to many data and to many work to do to use only console (and the DDBB it's too big as well).

Before checking the "use old auth.." the error message was:

```
Error connecting to datasource "MySQL - DDBB"
  SQL Error [1044] [42000]: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'information_schema'
    Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'information_schema'
```

Which make sense since the information schema table does not exists in that MySQL version (so i been told)

After checking and using the old auth method, the error is:

```
Your connection attemp failed for user 'user' from your host to server at ...... MySQL version is older than 5.0, which is not supported.
```

Anyone has an old client or the possiblity to bypass the old auth and work with a visual client for MySQL 4.1?

Comment: HeidiSQL worked just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heidi SQL worked just fine.

Also, you can try http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to connect in DBeaver using the MariahDB drivers which have the authentication method built in.